# How to fetch Options from API for Select when it is opened (onOpen event) in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI Select in my Project. Since i have lots of dropdowns with lots of options,i want to populate them only if they are opened by user.

On triggering the onOpen event,A call will be made and options will be fetched. Only problem is that i cannot fetch the name of Dropdown from event object passed in onOpen event.

The event is MouseDown. Which does not contain that information.

How to solve that???

**Is there any other event i can use??**

**Is this the standard way of doing this?**

Here is the code..

onOpen Handle function

```
const handleSelectOpen = (event,a) => {
    console.log(event.target.name  ) //returns undefined
    fetchData([reqDimName], filtersFormatted).then((data) => {
       
      });
  };
```

Select Component.

```
                      <Select
                          name={label.split('.')[1]}
                          label={
                            filterDimensions[e]?.meta?.current?.[
                            `${filterDimensions[e].metaTable}.${label.split('.')[1]}`
                            ]
                          }
                          onChange={filters[e].eventHandler}
                          value={filters[e].value?.[label.split('.')[1]] ? filters[e].value?.[label.split('.')[1]] || "" : [] || ""}
                          onOpen={handleSelectOpen}
                          multiple
                          renderValue={(selected) => (
                            <Box
                              sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}
                            >
                              {selected.map((value, j) => (
                                <Chip
                                  key={i} // use uniqueId to generate a unique key prop
                                  // key={`chip-${j}`}
                                  label={value}
                                />
                              ))}
                            </Box>
                          )}

                        >
                          {
                         
                             Object.keys(filters[e].items).length > 0
                              ? filters[e].items?.[label.replace('Meta',"")]
                                ?.filter((e) =>
                                  props.selectedDataType?.id
                                    ? e.dataTypeId == props.selectedDataType.id
                                    : true
                                )
                                ?.map((e, i) => (
                                  <MenuItem
                                    key={i} // use uniqueId to generate a unique key prop
                                    // key={`cascadingMenuItem-${i}`}
                                    value={e.option ? e.option : null}
                                    classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
                                  >
                                    {e.option ? e.option : 'null'}
                                  </MenuItem>
                                ))
                              : null
                              }
                        </Select>
```